# Scala flatten class

Tags: scala

I have defined the following classes in Scala:

```
case class Info {
    name: String,
    age: Int,
    dept: String
}


case class Foo {
    id: String,
    info: Info    
}
```

Is there a way to obtain automatically the following class from Foo and Info:

```
case class FlatFoo {
    id: Option[String],
    name: Option[String],
    age: Option[Int].
    dept: Option[String]
}
```

Comment: do you want to create an instance of FlatFoo from Foo and Info? Or do you actually create a class FlatFoo?

Comment: Why would you want this? And under what circumstances are the fields None or Some?

Comment: I don't want to create an instance of FlatFoo from Foo and Info but class definition of FlatFoo from Foo and Info classes.
If I add a new field in Info (e.g. surname: String), the FlatFoo class should be updated automatically (with surname: Option[String]). This is the reason I would like to do it (if it is possible).

Comment: what about using reflections to access dynamically in `FlatFoo` to methods from `Info` and `Foo` ?

Comment: Do you mean to create the type FlatFoo at run-time?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and assume the reason you want to have this 'flat' class is because of nesting objects. So you might want to look at Lenses? https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle, for instance

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul same idea same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a task for a very hardcore macro.
But I wonder if you just want to shorten your field accessors like 
`obj.fieldX.fieldY.fieldZ....`
In that case you might be interested in concept named [Lens](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Lens.html). Which is beautifully implemented in [monocle library](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle)

Consider such definition of your case classes:

```
import monocle.macros.Lenses

@Lenses
case class Info(name: String,
                age: Int,
                depts: List[String]
               )
@Lenses
case class User(id: String,
               info: Info
              )
```

That `@Lenses` attribute generates special functional getter&setter for each field . Those lenses are located implicitly in companion object. But you could add your own, composing existent.

```
import monocle.function.Index._
import monocle.std.list._
object User {
  val name = info ^|-> Info.name
  val age = info ^|-> Info.age
  val mainDept = info ^|-> Info.depts ^|-? index(0)
}
```

Now having

```
val oleg = User("odomontois", Info("Oleg", 23, List("python", "ABAP")))
```

You can see that

```
User.mainDept.getOption(oleg) == Some("python")

(User.age.set(28) andThen User.mainDept.set("scala")) (oleg) ==
  User("odomontois",Info("Oleg",28,List("scala", "ABAP")))
```